# About Framework7-vue-cli Ajax Interceptor

Tags: ajax, vue.js, html-framework-7

I want to intercept all ajax requests with a status code of -1 in all response and redirect it to the login screen. But I have been unable to monitor it. What should I do? Thank you.

My method：
app.js
`Framework7.Dom7(document).on('ajaxComplete', function(e){
  console.log('Monitored')
})`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Create a new file name `interceptors.js`

**interceptors.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue'


export default function setup() {

    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (config) {
        // Do something before the request is sent

        return config;
    }, function (error) {
        // Do something with request error

        return Promise.reject(error);
    });

}
```

then in your `app.js` import the `interceptors.js`

**app.js**

```
import interceptorsSetup from './interceptors';
interceptorsSetup()
```

Comment: I am requesting data using app.request.post (URL, data, success, error, data type). What if I don't need axios? thanks